# Trouble with subfloats/subcaption/subfigure

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I compiled my tex file in Linux without any problems (text edior: Xemacs). I'm now running the file in TeXWorks with MikteX. I used the `subfig` package and the following worked perfectly:

```
\subfloat{\label{fig:a}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.12]{somefigname.jpg}}
```

or

```
\subfloat[n=50]{\label{fig:a}}{\includegraphics[scale=0.14]{someotherfigname.jpg}}
```

I kept getting the 'undefined control sequence' error after trying to compile it in Win7. Having done some research, I installed the caption package (by running `pdflatex caption.ins`) and changed the `\subfloat` command above to `\subcaption`. Now instead of the error above, I'm getting two new:

``` ! Package caption Error: For a successful cooperation we need at least version
               ``2004/02/13 v1.2' of package listings,
                but only version
                ``2002/04/01 1.0 (Carsten Heinz)'
                is available. ```

The second one is:

```
! LaTeX Error: Counter too large.
```

When trying to install the `caption` package through mpm, I keep getting the 'connection failure' error.

I'm kind of lost here and have no idea what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It seems that your `listings` package is quite old.  I would suggest you upgrade to TeXLive2012 unless there is a really good reason to use a very old distribution.

Comment: Either install TeX Live 2012 or upgrade to MiKTeX 2.9: your MiKTeX distribution seems quite old. If you don't have disk space constraints, do a full install.